# Elasticsearch : How to match non existant tags

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, tire

Lets say I have a set of document which have a-z as keys.
And I am firing this term query:

```
curl -X GET localhost:9200/memphis/pincode/_search?pretty=json -d '{"query":{"term":{"a":"abcd", "b":"wxyz"}}}'
```

This will return me all the documents for which the value of 'a' is abcd and the value of 'b' is wxyz.
But, what if I want all the such documents in return for which (the value of 'a' is abcd and the value of 'b' is wxyz) or (the value of 'a' is abcd and tag 'b' doesn't exist) or (tag a doesn't exist and the value of 'b' is wxyz).

Is this possible.

I am working in ruby and am using 'Tire' gem to connect to elasticsearch. So would be more helpful if I get the corresponding syntax for tire as well.

Thanks In Advance

-Azitabh

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap 2 queries in a Bool Query with should clauses.

That means that the doc which hit the two queries will have an higher score.

See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-query.html

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer on some other forum.
Putting here just for the sake of completeness:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/missing-filter.html

```
{
"query" : {
    "constant_score" : {
        "filter" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "term": {"a" : "abcd"}
                        },
                        {
                            "missing": {"field": "a"}
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "term": {"b" : "wxyz"}
                        },
                        {
                            "missing": {"field": "b"}
                        }
                    ]
                },

            ]
        }
    }
}
}
```